# Build doc sets in Xcode 4 using Doxygen

Tags: xcode4, doxygen

HOw do I build docsets in Xcode 4 with Doxygen?

Apple's documentation refers to Xcode 3 and doesn't seem to apply to Xcode 4.

I think it might have to use a schemas (schemata?) rather than targets, but I'm not 100% certain.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build documentation as part of a dedicated target:

- In the project navigator, click on the project.
- In the right pane, add a new aggregate target (in MacOSX/Other) and name it **Documentation**
- In this target, add a new **Run Script** build phase
- In this build phase, invoke the Doxygen command line:

> /Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen

- Once the DocSet is built, copy it into `/Users/<YourName>/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets` folder.
- The new docset should appear into the help browser.

Answer (score 2):

It seems documentation for Xcode 3 works fine with Xcode 4.
I followed instructions (see *Using Doxygen to Create Xcode Documentation Sets on Documentation*) and everything is fine excerpt Xcode does not load the brand new docset.

I then examined the *AppleScript* command on the given run script and tested it on *AppleScript* editor : execution result was false. Error was the name of the docset file was missing.

By adding the docset filename the *AppleScript* script run successfully and the docset is well inserted to documentation :

Before :

```
echo "load documentation set with path \"/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/\""
```

After :

```
echo "load documentation set with path \"/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.mycompany.DoxygenExample.docset\""
```

Comment: If you create a user build setting APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER and set it to the app identifier, then replace com.mycompany.DoxygenExample with ${APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER} you also get a much more generalizable script. :)